# Questions about after the game ends... but *NOT* about what to play next!

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Yesterday, [Steve V](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5398/steve-v) marked a series of questions with [after-the-plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-plot). A good tag, but there was a short discussion in chat as to whether it should be renamed to something like [post-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-game), which is a more common monicker for gameplay after the "resolution of the main plot".

But post-game specifically refers to gameplay, not story. You don't call the ending or the spin-off books "post-game". That is one scenario where a classification of "after the plot" would be valid but not "post-game".

[All 6 questions with the tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-plot), *as far as I can tell*, are about post-game activity and not story. And I think there have been questions about endings and such, which do not have this tag. I'm thus not sure that we necessarily need a separate tag to differentiate story/plot questions that occur after the main story versus during the normal course.

I'm thinking of doing a rename and then establishing a synonym of [after-the-plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-plot) → [post-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-game), under the assumption that we don't expect any questions about story to need a post-resolution tag.

> #### Quick Insertion
>
> [In chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/568904#568904), [Powerlord](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2974/powerlord) mentioned the idea of [epilogue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epilogue). For the most part, epilogue tends to much more often relate to just the plot elements, and so it may be a good option if we do need a separate tag for post-resolution story that won't be frequently confused with post-game.

This session of the Dark Assembly is now in order. Aye or nay?

Comment: So, where does this leave us in terms of an enforceable decision? Using [tag:post-game]?

Comment: @Shaun That seems to be the conclusion, but there's no haste here for this one. I figure giving a full week is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aye. (I'm in full agreement and have nothing to add)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is a moot discussion at this point, since none of the tags mentioned exist any more. And good riddance; they were bad tags anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why not "end-game", it's the terminology usually associated with exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: end-game *could* be confused with the game's ending.  I still think this is the best answer though.

Answer (score 0):

**Nay.** Keep [after-the-plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-plot) as is, it's fine.

Comment: Also, I don't actually agree with this, but the opinion had to be posted to properly poll votes.

Comment: Who said this was a poll? This is not a popularity contest, if you have a valid reason against the synonym please do share it.

Comment: Well, "I'm in full agreement and have nothing to add".

Comment: Considering that people are downvoting both of these answers, I don't think this is having the exact intended effect. :(

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, I don't like either option. I'd prefer [after-the-credits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-credits). It's immediately obvious as the same phrase is used to refer to easter eggs after movies and it can cover anything from plot to things you can do in-game after you beat the end guy.